# what might cause SQLServer to stop accepting new database connections while preserving old ones?

Tags: sql-server-2005

A working IIS7 website gets restarted and its websites cannot connect to the database server.  All code is fine and unchanged and works if I point to another database server.  Database server has been restarted and shows no errors.  Network connections seem fine (syn-ack ok between servers).  The only errors are app pool crash errors on IIS server.  There was a failed red-gate backup job not long before I expreienced these problems, but all database hardware seems fine.  I'm guessing that something's wrong on the database server (OS or application) but I haven't found anything yet.... thanks, in advance, for any informed ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the connections to the server pool has been exhausted or are limited by the server and it's connections? Since the database server has been restarted, it would mean the number of the database connections would have been reset. FYI there was an article on CodeProject about [connection pooling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ADONET_ConnectionPooling.aspx)  and ADO.NET here. It could be down to poor programming practice where the connection is being kept open and not disposed of.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Please see comment below, I don't think this is caused by the web server code or side of things ... the effect is that any web application I recycle (app pool) cannot reconect to the database - no code change and db connection code that's worked for a year in production environment without issue or memory leaks.  I am, in effect, decreasing the number of connection pools every time I do this and I've had many more connections before ....  Thanks again for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

- changing DB server will reset connection pool
- have you restarted web server? not just IIS... you bounced the DB box so why not web
- what is the actual error in web code?

I agree with tommieb75: "smells" like connection pooling

Comment: Thank you, I did restart the web server.  Error is in event log ... app pool crash.  Same code works fine on copy of database on another server.  I really think it has something to do with network, OS, or application on database server.
The thing about connection pooling is that I've had way more conection pools before and I'm just stopping and restarting existing web services (and losing them as a result) with no code changes for a long time or since last restarts.  Thanks for your help!